Minimizing and simplifying a 2D triangle mesh
Goal:
I have a list of lots of triangles on a 2D surface, represented as std::vector<QPolygonF>. I want to transform this list into another list of triangles that have the same outline, but no triangles overlap. In other words, I want to merge overlapping triangles:

Questions:
Is there a name for this process? What is the best way to do that with Qt? Is there a well-known algorithm for this that I can implement if Qt doesn't support it natively?

That doesn't seem a minimization nor a simplification, and in the second case it seems that you're also creating new arbitrary segments.

@musicamante I am creating a new set of triangles that preserve the overall outline but do not overlap with each other.

We understand that, I was pointing out that what you want is not a minimization nor a simplification. In fact, it's a complex problem that can have different results even with the same group of overlapping triangles (as in the second example above, there are probably at least other 2 alternate solutions). See Polygon triangulation.

@musicamante if you can propose a more accurate title, I would be happy to change it. Thank you for the feedback.

The "Polygon triangulation" may be a good hint. That said, I must stress again the fact that what you're asking is not as simple as it seems you may believe. In fact, even if I'm not aware of specific libraries that may deal with this (and Qt certainly isn't, as it's not in its scope), your problem is mostly about math and geometry. The same triangle configuration may give very different results depending on the stacking order you may prefer. Even having just two colliding triangles may give quite different results: if their vertexes do not enclose each other, then you'll have up to two »

» possible and very different results, depending on the stacking order (consider the simple case of the Hexagram). But, if they are enclosed, things become more complex. In case one triangle is completely within the area of the other (assuming no common vertexes), you'll end up with at least 4 triangles (if all inside vertexes are on one of the outside triangle sides), and possibly up to 7 inner triangles. And the situation may become even more difficult to analyze when any of the corners collide with the other triangle's corner or edge, or they »

» are outside of its area. And now that I'm considering again your example image, I can see at least a dozen of other possibilities, depending on the "priority" of the triangles for the second example: you seem to be basing the "second" result based on the triangle with the leftmost corner (and even in that case you don't consider the priorities of the other two topmost triangles). What you're asking is not impossible, but it has many possible implementations (and related effectiveness) that depend on your requirement, which, right now, are not clear. And some are also difficult to achieve.

What you are asking is difficult, if not very difficult. As far as I know, this problem is not commonly solved and is certainly not implemented in Qt.
A line of attack can be by

merging all triangles to polygons (as many polygons as there are connected sets of triangles); see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/how-to-union-many-polygons-efficiently

triangulating the resulting polygon(s), for example by ear-clipping. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation


Beware that after merging, you can get polygons with holes.



It should also be noted that any set of n>1 colliding triangles may result in very different combinations of minimum triangle count. Even a relatively simple case of two colliding triangles creating an irregular hexagon, could result in up to 10 (at least) different configurations. Right now it's not even clear if the OP is looking for a minimum amount of triangles, or they need to follow a specific stacking order, both of which could dramatically change the triangle count (and the computation difficulty).

@musicamante: the union of the triangles is unique and triangulating an n-gon yields n-2 triangles. This is optimal.

The union of triangles is certainly not unique. Just overlap two different triangles creating an irregular hexagram, and you'll have two different possibilities depending on which of the triangles stacks "above". And it certainly is not very optimal, as your second example has far more triangles than the one proposed by the OP.

@musicamante: no you don't understand. After union, there is a single polygonal domain, which is uniquely defined by its outline(s).

@musicamante: regarding optimality, you are right. The number of triangles may be reduced by adding Steiner points. I am not familiar with Steiner triangulation.

I would use an algorithm such as this to find where lines intersect. If 2 intersection points also have a shared vertex, you have created a triangle. You also need to keep track of the areas covered by each triangle. It seems you want to keep the largest triangle. If a large triangle completely covers a smaller triangle, the smaller triangle can be removed. The only problem I see with your diagram is the smallest rectangle you created (in agreement with musicamante), in the 2nd transformation, by randomly choosing to use the vertex of the bottom right triangle. If you are using random vertices to make new triangles, why not form every triangle possible around the perimeter of the diagram out of all the exposed vertices? If you want to use an algorithm, you need to be consistent about its usage.
I don't think this is necessarily a programming problem, more of an algorithm problem. Maybe solve it first in Python, then implement in C++/qt?

What you are after is the (Boolean) union of a group of polygons, see this Wikipedia page, without holes (which requires extra computation as @yvesdaoust mentions), whilst preserving the inner edges that have not been broken in the process.
I think that is a customised operation that has no name at the moment. The links on the Wikipedia page are very old but may be a good start for a search - it looks like the clipper2 library can do the union part of what you want? Restoring the still-triangle-edges may take some extra coding.
